# Sorting arrays (2D array) Need assistance

Tags: javascript, arrays

Basiclly what i am trying to do is for sort the values of a array input like `uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1])` into a sorted 2D array like `[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [4], [3], [5]]`. **The arrays don't have to be in number/ value order**. The code below is what i tried:

```
function uniteUnique(arr) {
    let times = 0;
    var unique = [[]];
    for (var i = 0; i < Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).length; i++) {
        times = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < arguments[i].length; j++) {
            for (var h = 0; h < unique.length; h++) {
                var pushArray = []
                if(unique[h][0] === arguments[i][j]) {
                    unique[h].push(arguments[i][j]) 
                    arguments[i].splice(j)
                } 
                else {
                    unique.push([arguments[i][j]])
                }
            }
        }
    }
   return unique
}

uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]);
```

--> https://repl.it/@John_Nicole/unique

**I only have one parameter for all of the input arrays**

---

I have a `unique`array with 1 blank array. Its a 2D array.

Then i go through, for instance, the values of `[1, 3, 2]` and check if any arrays in `unique`have there first value as my number (`arguments[i][j]`).

If true, i push the number `arguments[i][j]`, then remove the number in the original array with `splice()` .

If false, i push new array into `unique` with this unrecognized value.

**Quick Overview of the variables**

- `h`: This is the array in `unique` that i am going to compare with. It could be `[2, 2, 2]`.
- `i`: This is the array from the input. For instance, `[1, 3, 2]`.
- `j`: This the number itself, its partner with `i`. For example, `arguments[i][j]` = `[2, 1]` --> `2`
- `arguments` grabs all, in this case, the 3 input arrays.
- `Times`: This just means 0. No use what so ever.

The input could include 2D arrays in themselves like `[1, 3, 2], [1, [5]], [2, [4]]`

This is a part of a freeCodeCamp challenge --> https://www.freecodecamp.org/challenges/sorted-union

---

My question is that, why is my output:

```
[ [],
  [ 1, 1 ],
  [ 5, 5 ],
  [ 5 ],
  [ undefined, undefined ],
  [ 2, 2 ],
  [ 2 ],
  [ 2 ],
  [ 2 ],
  [ 2 ],
  [ undefined, undefined ],
  [ undefined, undefined ],
  [ undefined, undefined ],
  [ undefined, undefined ] ]
```

?
when the wanted output is: Wanted output was `[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [4], [3], [5]`

Am i doing something wrong?

I'm getting multiple `2`'s arrays for example (`[[ 2 ],[ 2 ],[ 2 ],[ 2 ]]`) even though i'm suppose to be putting all `2` into one array?

---

Comment: the required result is different from the given code challenge. which one do you like to get?

Comment: I'm just trying to sort them by value in a array, so i know just how many their are. I'm going to add them all up and decide by how many starting arrays their are to see if its either a unique value and only present in one array, or is present in all. Some of the examples in the requirements show this.

Comment: I just edited my post so its less confusing

Comment: Another approach would be `const flat = arr => arr.reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b),[]); const unique = arr =>  [...new Set(arr)]; const uniqueSet = arr => unique(flat(arr));`

Comment: ES5? Would this output multiple arrays that have each value sorted? (e.x. being at the top of my post). I'm going to need it later on. No offense, but please re-read the post. I edited it 5 or 6 times just now to clear up any confusion, i didn't know if something didn't make sense to you just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hash table and check if the hash key exists and if not, then take an empty array as value for the hash and push it to the result set.

> The hash table is an object (here without prototypes) which takes the values as keys and an array as value. A the the end the hash table keeps all values in arrays, which are inserted in the result set if a new value is found.
>
> ```
> {
>     1: [1, 1, 1],
>     2: [2, 2, 2],
>     3: [3],
>     4: [4],
>     5: [5]
> }
> ```

```js
function uniteUnique() {
    var result = [],
        hash = Object.create(null);
        
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments, function (a) {
        a.forEach(function (b) {
            if (!(b in hash)) {
                hash[b] = [];
                result.push(hash[b]);
            }
            hash[b].push(b);
        });
    });
    return result;
}

console.log(uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

---

Some annotation to your code (not used variables are deleted):

```js
function uniteUnique() {
    var unique = [],                                    // move all declarations to top
        i, j, h,
        pushed;

    // array like objects have a length property
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < arguments[i].length; j++) {
            pushed = false;
            for (h = 0; h < unique.length; h++) {
                if (unique[h][0] === arguments[i][j]) {
                    // take the element, do not use splice, because with splicing
                    // the array becomes shorter and the index is updated in the
                    // next loop and is pointing to the element with the wrong index,
                    // because you get the element after next
                    // it is better not to mutate a variable, if it works without
                    // in this case, you iterate and visit each element only once
                    unique[h].push(arguments[i][j]);
                    pushed = true;                      // a value is found
                    break;                              // exit this loop
                }                                       // prevent more looping
            }
            if (!pushed) {                              // if not found
                unique.push([arguments[i][j]]);         // push the value
            }
        }
    }
    return unique;
}

console.log(uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The input isn't a 2D array. ```uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]);```

Comment: How do hash tables work? How far off was my original code? I'm still confused on how this works, and i don't want to use code i don't understand.

Comment: Wow that is cool. It doesn't seem over complicated either. Ill continue to look up has tables too. What does the ! mean?

Comment: its a [logical NOT `!`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT) operator with and [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) which checks if a given key is in an object/array.

Comment: Oh okay., and  ```n3 = !'Cat'``` means the same thing as ```n3 !== 'Cat'```?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160353/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-leed).

Comment: I asked a question in our discussion (just encase you didnt see).